# VistaDB Connection Issue Programmatically using SQLConnection and ConnectionString

Tags: connection, vistadb

I'm getting an error connecting to a VistaDB using a connection string in the web.config file.

It works fine using a SQLDataSource AFTER I specified the ProviderName. On another page I'm only connecting in code and

*Here is the code for the connection string:*

Public Function CreateConnection() As SqlConnection
    _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString()
    Return New SqlConnection(_connectionString)
End Function

*Here is the error:*

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

**How can I resolve this error?**

Comment: I am getting the same error. Haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a SqlConnection with a VistaDB connection string.  That is the error you are getting from SQL Server - it can't find that server.

Use a VistaDBConnection instead.